# Can I use another gpg keyserver when all given gpg keyserver are not available?

Tags: docker, gpg-signature, keyserver

I'm trying to build a docker image with given dockerfiles: https://github.com/31z4/storm-docker/blob/4c2804fa4365f62c3b6009d3496661542e4d446a/2.2.0/Dockerfile

But `docker build` command occurs an error as below:

> - gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 79B03D059E628478FC9F1D8B152CAD0C46E87B61 gpg: keybox
>   '/tmp/tmp.r0rdSZG7mG/pubring.kbx' created gpg: keyserver receive
>   failed: Connection timed out
> - gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 79B03D059E628478FC9F1D8B152CAD0C46E87B61 gpg: keyserver receive
>   failed: Connection timed out
> - gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys 79B03D059E628478FC9F1D8B152CAD0C46E87B61 gpg: keyserver receive
>   failed: Connection timed out

I'm not familiar to gpg keyserver, but it seems that some keyserver addresses are exchangeable.

Can I find another gpg keyserver that can replace the existing keyservers?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `bash` script that allows you to check upon multiple sources:
https://github.com/duxsco/gpg-config-and-scripts#pull-public-keys

You could also do:

```
gpg --auto-key-locate clear,dane,wkd,pka,cert,hkps://keys.openpgp.org,hkps://keys.mailvelope.com,hkps://keys.gentoo.org,hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --locate-external-keys <KeyID>
```